# Is there a way to pass the aggregated value to the tooltip encoding on a simple histogram in Vega Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to add the value of the count to the tooltip in the simple way to a simple histogram plot in Vega Lite?

Something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "data/movies.json"
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": [
      {
        "field":  "Count of Records",
        "type": "quantitative"
      }
    ],
    "x": {
      "bin": true,
      "field": "IMDB_Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "count",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
}
```

There does not seem to be a way to reference the aggregated y encoding in the tooltip encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooltips are encodings just like any other; you can pass the same arguments to the tooltip that you do to the y encoding:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "data/movies.json"
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": [
      {
        "aggregate": "count",
        "type": "quantitative"
      }
    ],
    "x": {
      "bin": true,
      "field": "IMDB_Rating",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "count",
      "type": "quantitative"
    }
  }
}
```

See it in action [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSBXATgGxSjkQHoBbAewDcBLAUwGcA6AKwYoDtJwwBfAGh6QysHAGtCkAEajIgzHQ4BjCtBocA5oXQZI8ChTzwaAB0IBtHhjRXrUWBo046GhHUkqsHeHNvW9AJ4m7qiQAI5YsN40iMZU7n58tgC68roAHtqJ0uqE8DhYdGn+AGb0eNCSAJIAsgAiAEIA+gBKCOpaxbrwQSFQEVHGsTTx3NYCtpABWXb2js6u8H2Qnt6+s4HBkgPRw6O2vDyHvEA).